# AngularJS digest nuance or am I just dumb? ng if renders component twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Unfortunately, I am not able to create a reproducible snippet for this scenario. It's occurring in a rather complicated codebase, suffice it to say.

I have a component method `onClick` that sets a flag to true.
e.g.

```
// in the template
<button type='button' ng-click="onClick()"></button>

//javascript

angular.module('myModule')
  .component('MyComponent', {
  ...
  controller: [function(){
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.showModal = false;
    ctrl.onClick = function() {
      ctrl.showModal = true;
    }
  }]
})
```

This flag is used with an `ng-if` that instantiates another component that `$onInit` renders a modal. e.g.

```
//in the template

<my-modal-component ng-if="$ctrl.showModal"></my-modal-component>


//javascript
angular.module('myModule')
  .component('myModalComponent', {
  ...
  controller: [function(){
    // renders third party modal
    var renderModal = function() {}
   
    // makes and returns an api call to get some data as a promise
    var getRelevantData = function(){}


    this.$onInit = function () {
      getRelevantData().then(function(){
        renderModal();
      })
    }
  }]
})
```

For some crazy reason, `myModalComponent` actually gets two separate instances (i.e. renders twice, one on top of the other) when the button is clicked. I know there's some `ng-if` nuances with scope but I'm not using `$scope` here, and even putting the flag inside an object didnt work.

`ng-show` with some if checks on rendering the modal sort of works but my data bindings get all screwed up (a method I pass into `myModalComponent` is defined when ng-show is false but when ng-show changes to true, it's undefined) so I prefer to not go down that rabbit hole if I can; plus, I think ng-if makes much more sense here.

Even more crazy, if I put a `$timeout(, 10000)` to delay the setting of the flag to 10 seconds on the button click (`onClick`), *the modal still renders once immediately and ten seconds later, another modal renders on top of it.*

Admittedly, I try to stay away from the digest cycle, as I know it's something important to know but ironically is kind of an anti-pattern to mess with... So does anyone have any ideas?

I miss React.

Comment: Which version of AngularJS are you using? I've heard about duplicate digest cycle problems occurring in <=1.6.x but improved in 1.7.x

Comment: @JacobStamm 1.5.9, sigh. That sounds like what I'm experiencing. Do you have an issue link? What's even crazier is that the same modal component with a very similar paradigm is used in 3 other places and all work great over there -.-

Comment: Why is your modal's template using its own element tags?

Comment: @MarkClark the modal template is its own component. I componentized it because it's used in 4 different places in our app so I didnt have to re-invent the same modal in the said 4 places and instead, can just plug it in via <my-modal-component>

Comment: I'm referring to the element name. Much like directives, you can instantiate a component with a reserved element/tag name. By placing <my-modal-component> in its own template, you are telling the component to instantiate itself (again) by using its own element selector.

Comment: @MarkClark Oh the code blocks are not necessarily all within the same file / component. Sorry for the confusion.  The second code block shows my-modal-component being used where it is displayed but the source javascript of my-modal-component does not have a template / associated templateUrl

Comment: Could you create a minimal reproduction on codepen/jsfiddle/plunkr? I know you mentioned it was a more complex app but if we can at least get a clear picture of your application hierarchy and component instantiation specific to this issue, that would go a long way in debugging.

Comment: In addition to what @MarkClark said, make sure it's using your exact version of AngularJS as well

Comment: @JacobStamm and mark sorry guys, in bit of a crunch. I ended up upgrading AngularJs to 1.8 and the problem went away, so I'm happy to assume this is a < 1.6 issue like Jacob mentioned first. I don't really have time to get a reproducible snippet up, but  thank you both for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was using angular 1.5.9. Ive seen other digest issues but dealt with them independently but this one was more-or-less a show stopper. So upgraded to 1.8 and problem went away.